# convert a list of dictionaries to a dictionary with dict comprehension

Tags: python

Original:

```
# abs is not a string, it's a function name 
[{'name': 'abs'}, {'op': abs}]
```

to

```
{'name': 'abs', 'op': abs}
```

My code:

```
op = [{'name': 'abs'}, {'op': abs}] # key value is unique 
new_dict = {}
for item in op:
    new_dict.update(item)
```

Is there a way to do the same with dict comprehension?

Comment: You'd be looking for a **dictionary** comprehension. Do all of your initial dicts only have one entry or could they contain several?

Comment: second `abs` is a variable name, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
list_of_dicts = [{'name': 'abs'}, {'op': abs}]
new_dict = {k: v for element in list_of_dicts for k, v in element.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
{'name': 'abs', 'op': <built-in function abs>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict`

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'name': 'abs'}, {'op': abs}]
print(dict(tuple(*i.items()) for i in data))
```

**Output:**

```
{'name': 'abs', 'op': <built-in function abs>}
```